# Is there a best practice to test your stack locally before deploying to AWS and avoid deploying your stack over and over during debuggin?

Tags: amazon-web-services, testing, deployment, aws-cloudformation

I have been working with AWS and the Serverless Framework/Cloud Formation over the last few months.
A solid amount of time went into debugging my applications and most of this time share went into staring at my console while my stack is being deployed.

I did read in „The Software Craftsman“ (Sandro Mancuso) that the Author worked for a company where the developers where working in a similar fashion: Changing a tiny bit of code, deploying all of the code to the server, executing it, checking print statements before again changing a tiny bit of code and deploying all the code again.

Mancaso heavily criticized this approach and strongly recommended to write tests before deployment to avoid this kind of behavior. Since I currently am developing in a pretty much exactly the same fashion, I gave this approach some thought, but I came across some issues.

Of cause testing is very important and it catches some issues I would have missed before deploying my code. However, when working on cloud infrastructure, microservices and other distributed systems, there are a lot of aspects I simply can not capture in my tests. Errors stemming from the AWS Infrastructure itself, errors stemming from Interaction with other micro services or connected systems etc.

Therefore I am looking for a way (if any exists) to test my AWS stack locally in any way, to avoid changing tiny bits of code and then waiting for my code to deploy to AWS for a few minutes during debugging.

Comment: There is not sensible way to test locally, some services can be emulated locally, but most cannot and you always risk the emulation to not reflect the real world properly.

Answer (score 1):

I have not found yet a perfect solution to it. Even if you are testing code locally, with some mocked services, it still can fail after deployment, because you forgot to combine the IAM rights, permissions, security groups, policies etc.

Currently I am working with AWS CLI, which creates Cloud Formation stacks. We can test an Lambda locally, this is not a problem, but even if it communicates with your local DB, it can fail after deployment, as the DB in your account is in VPC and you forgot to change the policies...

Our approach is currently to work with nested stacks, so that we don't have to redeploy entire infrastructure, but only that one part, that was really changed.

Nested stacks works good with AWS CLI.